# Swift Firestore cannot get data to Object

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

Hello i try to parse a array of strings into a dao. To do so i created this:

```
   func getUsersAbos(){
let userid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
let docRef = db.collection("Users").document(userid!)

docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
if let city = document.flatMap({
$0.data().flatMap({ (data) in
    return UserBlogObject(channelAbos: data)
})
}) {
print("City: \(city)")
} else {
print("Document does not exist")
}
}
}
```

and here is my Dao:

import Foundation
 class UserBlogObject{
    var channelAbos = Any

```
init(channelAbos: [String]) {
    self.channelAbos = channelAbos


}

init(){

}
```

}

i get an error at this line:

```
        return UserBlogObject(channelAbos: data)
```

> Cannot convert value of type '[String : Any]' to expected argument type '[String]'

please note that i want to download just an array inside the document, not the whole document.

Comment: First please edit your question and correct indents and code formatting. It makes it much easier for people to provide good answers when the code is easy to read. And to answer your question, Firestore gives a `Dictionary` of `[String : Any]` where the string is the key for the value and Any is the value itself. So, handle a dictionary in your init method instead of an array of `[String]`

Comment: thanks but i wanna get only the array for the key channelAbos in my document

Comment: You can then use the ["key"] to get the array. I will post a quick answer. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this. I don't think there is a need to overcomplicate the function with `flatMap()` but you can do it if you want. Here is a code example of how you could create your method.

```
func getUsersAbos() {
    guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    let docRef = db.collection("Users").document(userID)
    docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if error != nil { return }
        guard let data = document?.data() else { return }
        guard let channelAbos = data["channelAbos"] as? [String] else { return }
        let userBlogObject = UserBlogObject.init(channelAbos: channelAbos) // This is the created object. Handle it.
    }
}
```

And your class:

```
class UserBlogObject {
    var channelAbos : [String]

    init(channelAbos: [String]) {
        self.channelAbos = channelAbos
    }
}
```